# My notification icon/message is cleared when app exits or phone is restarted

Tags: android, notifications

I looked around a lot for an answer but guess i must be missing something obvious...

When a user does a certain operation in my app i wish to display an icon in the bar, aswell as a message in the "messages" dropdown.

This works fine, however, when my app is shut down (through the activity manager), or i restart the phone, all is cleared.

The icon is unavoidable i suppose, but i would like the message to only be cleared when the user clears it, and to be persistent across phone restarts.

Is this possible?

code:

```
Notification notification = new Notification(icon, message, when);
notification.flags = Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;

Context context = getApplicationContext();
CharSequence contentTitle = "Title";
CharSequence contentText = "The Message";
Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, MyActivity.class);
PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, notificationIntent, 0);
notification.setLatestEventInfo(context, contentTitle, contentText, contentIntent);
getNotificationManager().notify(STATUSBAR_ID, notification);
```

Comment: Check out this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5071598/android-make-notification-persist-across-phone-reboot

Comment: Wow, that was complicated... thanks man. If you put it as an answer, i can checkmark it for you? Can't believe i missed that answer, i searched for all sorts of wicked string combos... :)

Comment: Glad it helped.  I'll put it in an answer, and thanks for the follow up!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This SO answer should help you out on this:

"For raising a `Notification`, you can probably get by with just doing it in the `BOOT_COMPLETED_ACTION` `BroadcastReceiver`, rather than delegating it to a service. However, I agree, this is the only way to do it AFAIK."

[Android: make notification persist across phone reboot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5071598/android-make-notification-persist-across-phone-reboot)