# Are Urban Airship push notifications supposed to persist after reboot?

Tags: android, urbanairship.com

In my tests, my device receives Urban Airship push notifications as expected, but after rebooting the device, the UA notifications disappear from the Android status bar area. I'm surprised that unclicked notifications are absent after reboot because I would assume UA would handle the process of [re-adding the notifications after reboot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5071598/android-make-notification-persist-across-phone-reboot).

I don't see any promises of persistence in the UA documentation, so I'm not sure if this is expected behavior or not.

Comment: Notifications are OS level functions. In Androids case, they are delivered by GCM and handled by the OS. Third party platforms such as Urban Airship only deliver the message to GCM.

Comment: I think you meant they deliver messages "from GCM", not "to GCM". Anyway, you're mostly right, but in the case of UA for Android, the notification in the status area is owned by the UA layer - it is not seen by the app until the user taps on the notification, at which point the UA layer sends an intent to whatever Receiver you configured in your manifest.

In summary, if UA really wanted to, they could keep track of the un-tapped notifications and re-add them reboot. As mentioned in the accepted answer to this question, UA has confirmed that they do not support this feature.

Comment: UA > GCM > Device > App > UA SDK

Comment: I see now - you were talking about the initial stage where UA sends to GCM on the server-side. I mistakenly thought you were talking about the device-side unboxing, and I still think the device-side flow is Device > UA SDK > App, but perhaps you see it differently.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I reached the Urban Airship folks via email. They confirmed that UA does not attempt to persist push notifications. So it is expected behavior to lose them after reboots, for example.