# Same id for different notification

Tags: android, android-intent, alarmmanager, android-notifications, android-pendingintent

I've implemented an app that deals with notifications, which are setted programmatically, whit this codes:

```
 public void setAlarm(Cell cell, Long timeStamp, String title, String message) {
    Integer id = (int) System.currentTimeMillis();
    Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(context, receiver);
    notificationIntent.putExtra("ID", id);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, id, notificationIntent, 0);
    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    assert alarmManager != null;
    alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, timeStamp, 2 * 60 * DateUtils.SEC_TO_MILLIS, pendingIntent);
    RepositoryManager repositoryManager = RepositoryManager.getInstance();
    repositoryManager.storeNotificationAdministration(new NotificationAdministration(id, timeStamp, 2, title, message, 1, null, cell, StatusNotification.NOT_YET_NOTIFIED.getId()));
}
```

This is my receiver:

```
 @Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    RepositoryManager controllerDatabase = RepositoryManager.getInstance(ControllerDatabase.getInstance(context));
    NotificationMedicine notificationMedicine = controllerDatabase.getNotificationMedicine();
    if (notificationMedicine.getEnable()) {
        if (intent.hasExtra("ID")) {
            int id = intent.getIntExtra("ID", 0);
            NotificationManager mNotifyMgr =
                    (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
            Log.d("DEBUG", "MyReceiverAdministration " + id);
            try {
                NotificationAdministration notificationAdministration = controllerDatabase.findNotificationAdministrationById(id);

                NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
                        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_medicine)
                        .setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), R.mipmap.ic_launcher))
                        .setContentTitle(notificationAdministration.getTitle())
                        .setContentText(notificationAdministration.getMessage())
                        .setOngoing(false)
                        .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_HIGH)
                        .setAutoCancel(false);

                Intent i = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
                i.putExtra(SettingsData.TAG_CELL, notificationAdministration.getCell().getId());
                PendingIntent pendingIntent =
                        PendingIntent.getActivity(
                                context,
                                notificationAdministration.getId(),
                                i,
                                0
                        );
                Intent snoozeIntent = new Intent(context, MyFlagBroadcastReceiver.class);
                snoozeIntent.putExtra(SettingsData.TAG_CELL, notificationAdministration.getId());
                PendingIntent flagIt =
                        PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, snoozeIntent, 0);
                mBuilder.setLights(0x6098CF, 1000, 2000);
                Uri uriRingtone = notificationMedicine.getRingtone();
               mBuilder.setSound(uriRingtone);
                mBuilder.setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
                mBuilder.addAction(R.drawable.ic_timer_black_24dp, context.getString("Do my action"), flagIt);
                mNotifyMgr.notify(notificationAdministration.getId(), mBuilder.build());
                Vibrator v = (Vibrator) context.getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
                v.vibrate(700);
                notificationAdministration.setStatus(StatusNotification.NOTIFIED.getId());
                controllerDatabase.storeNotificationAdministration(notificationAdministration);
            } catch (ObjectNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is other Receiver, when the user click on the action of the notification:

```
 RepositoryManager controllerDatabase = RepositoryManager.getInstance(ControllerDatabase.getInstance(context));
        if (intent.hasExtra(SettingsData.TAG_CELL)) {
            int id = intent.getIntExtra(SettingsData.TAG_CELL, 0);
try {
                NotificationAdministration notificationAdministration = controllerDatabase.findNotificationAdministrationById(id);
                Device device = controllerDatabase.getDefaultDeviceByUser(controllerDatabase.getLoggedUser().getUser());
                Cell cell = controllerDatabase.findCellById(device, notificationAdministration.getCell().getId());
                Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
                Long now = calendar.getTimeInMillis() / DateUtils.SEC_TO_MILLIS;
                controllerDatabase.flagMedicineTaken(cell, now);
                NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
                if (mNotificationManager != null) {
                    mNotificationManager.cancel(id);
                }
            } catch (ObjectNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
```

The problem I'm facing is that the MyFlagBoradcastReceiver gets always the same ID of the notification and no the one that I'm pressing/clicking.

The idea of the app is to set different notifications, that are always visibile, untile the user click on the action of the notification. The alarm should be trigged also after 2 minutes...

** UPDATE **

This is the lines of code that I should use to cancel the alarm; what should I use as receiver?

```
AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
            Intent myIntent = new Intent(context,
                    receiver);
            PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(
                    context, notificationAdministration.getId(), myIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
            if (alarmManager != null) {
                alarmManager.cancel(pendingIntent);
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

When creating the `PendingIntent` for the `Notification`, you need to do this:

```
PendingIntent flagIt = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context,
                         notificationAdministration.getId(),
                         snoozeIntent, 0);
```

You need to make sure that each `PendingIntent` you create for `MyFlagBroadcastReceiver` is unique, otherwise Android will just return the existing `PendingIntent` instead of creating a new one. You can do this by providing a unique ID for each call to `PendingIntent.getBroadcast()`.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. It is better now the situation, by the way it seems the alarm is repeating, even if I've cancel it the pending; is it normal? Where am I wrong?

Comment: You set the alarm to be repeating. Post the code that you use to cancel the alarm (edit your orignal post and add the code there, please do NOT add the code here as a comment) and I'll look at it.

Comment: You only cancel the `Notification`. You never cancel the alarm. You need to call `AlarmManager.cancel() to cancel the alarm.

Comment: Thank you! By the way I've a question about your hint; what Should I use as receiver? The fact is that I just want to cancel the alarm, not to perform other operation with it. I've updated the post

Comment: Sorry I don't understand your question. What do you mean "what should I use as receiver"? You should add yout cancel code to the place where you want to cancel your alarm.

Comment: Yes I know it, bu what Should I put as "receiver" object for the Intent?

Comment: The same one you used when you set the alarm!

Comment: It is important to specify the PendingIntent flag?

Comment: No. You don't need to specify any flags.

Comment: ok! Is it normal that notifications are canceled/deleted after the reboot?

Comment: Yes. Notifications do not survive a reboot. Alarms do not survive a reboot. `PendingIntent`s do not survive a reboot. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5071598/android-make-notification-persist-across-phone-reboot